# Anyone know of a program that will mute sound if my headphones are removed?

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, headphones, mute

It really annoys me when my headphones get pulled out and my sound blasts through the speakers. I'd like it to just automatically mute. Does any software exist that will do this?

I'm running Windows 7, BTW.

Comment: I can't find any software for this, perhaps roll out your own? http://u.sbhat.me/jPMEGN

Comment: A sudden sound blast in office leads to embarrassing situations. +1

Comment: Sathya, I was considering it. However, the responses I was getting at Stack Overflow didn't look particularly promising. Like most hardware related things there isn't really a standard way of going about it. I'm not familiar enough with audio cards to write such a beast, yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a very simple reason why its not possible - when you plug in a pair of headphones, there's a small physical switch that cuts out main speakers so the system is not actually aware which is plugged in.

The 'simplest' solution is probably to use an external sound card, or a extention cord for your headphones (even a short one) - the latter would bypass the speakers totally, while the latter would keep the switch closed so no sound comes out

Its not a software solution but its a fairly simple hardware one

Comment: Not so - your sound hardware can recognize when headphones/speakers are plugged in (I think via impedance measurement). If your hardware and driver has this feature, then detecting it in software is possible (a quick Google search finds code examples for OS X). I don't know of any Windows software that will do this off the top of my head, though.

Comment: The cord **is** a hardware solution..

Comment: its a switch. since its a switch like the one in the article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS_connector#Switch_contacts, things like this work http://www.woodwardweb.com/technology/hardware_mute_h.html

Comment: corrected hardware to software. Thanks @Turbo J

Comment: You could try something like http://www.amazon.com/Griffin-SmartShare-Headphone-Splitter-Individual/dp/B000EHCYBC/ , which is compact, gives you hardware volume control and allows 2 people to listen to your mp3s on their headphones simultaneously!  *g*

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't know of any software that does it I am sure that it would be possible given that my sound card alerts via a popup me when I plug in or pull out anything attached to the headphone jack. Contra to what Mohan Gajula says I'd suggest asking Mr Google.

Comment: That was what I was thinking as well. There is definitely a way the computer detects it, on a software level (Or at least on most of my computers.). I may try to contact the company that made my driver and see if they have any insight. If I have any luck I'll try to host it somewhere as a FOSS solution.